# Cannon Find Symbols Error

Tags: java, eclipse

So I'm trying to run

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73
javac com/darkblade12/enchantplus/*.java
jar cvf program.jar -C com/darkblade12/enchantplus
```

in command prompt as I'm not fluent in any language or Eclipse, but I get a cannot find symbols error for many of the items "compiled", I originally just tried to recompile a .jar in Java7 rather than Java8 because I had the source code and needed it in the format for Java7, so any help with either would be great.

Comment: What symbols does it say it can't find?

Comment: symbol:   class Configuration
  location: class IndependantConfigurationSection
.\com\darkblade12\enchantplus\section\IndependantConfigurationSection.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
        public ConfigurationSection getConfigurationSection(Configuration root) throws SectionNotFoundException {
               ^

Comment: Is 'Configuration' a .java file in your enchantplus folder?

Comment: I should say, do you know where Configuration.java is?

Comment: There is no Configuration.java, but there is a IndependantConfigurationSection.java.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but, I guess you only want to compile your classes.
The value of `JAVA_HOME` variable has blanks in it. You might want to put it in quotes or use the windows shortened path names, like shown here [How can I find the short path of a Windows directory/file?](https://superuser.com/questions/348079/how-can-i-find-the-short-path-of-a-windows-directory-file.).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a source file, or possibly an external library your program depends on. If you find Configuration.java, you can add it to your enchantplus folder, maker sure to give it the same package name as the one in IndependantConfigurationSection.java and it should compile. If it is a .class file packaged in a .jar file,you need to add that jar to your classpath using

```
javac -cp {path-to-class-or-jar} com/darkblade12/enchantplus/*.java
```

Comment: Now there are only 83 errors, 3 warnings, but still the same cannot find symbol error. 
  symbol:   class ConfigurationSection
  location: class Settings
com\darkblade12\enchantplus\Settings.java:175: error: cannot find symbol
                ConfigurationSection levelStacking = LEVEL_STACKING.getConfigurationSection(config, false);
                ^ One of many errors.

Comment: Now you need to find the ConfigurationSection.java or .class file, and do the same thing

Comment: If my answer was helpful to you, please consider upvoting using the up arrow beside my answer, and accepting the answer as correct using the checkmark below the arrows.